# Using the old Facebook GraphAPI v1.0 for new App

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

currently we are developing an App based on the old GraphAPI - now called GraphAPI v1.0.

Now I'm wondering what is meant by "GraphAPI v1.0 will still be supported for one year".
The important question for us: Is it possible to launch the new app in a few weeks using the old v1.0? Or will Facebook refuse the app because we don't use the new one?
I did not find anything concerning the old API in the FB support documents and the answers in the FB dev group aren't clear neither.

Anyone knows more about that?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you created and were using the app before April 30th 2014, you can use API v1.0 until April 30th, 2015

If you created the app on or after April 30th 2014, or the app is old but had no activity, you must use v2.0 and cannot call version 1.0 from that app ID

Calling `/v1.0/<something>` will give the same behaviour as calling `/v2.0/<something>` for an app which was created after v2.0's release

There's a document here with more information about how versioning is implemented in the API and how to use it in apps: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/versions#calling_older_versions

Comment: what about calling /v1.0/<something> with v1.0 app created some time ago? why it is not working?

Comment: What call isn't working? Was your app active or did you recently restart using an old inactive app ID? the latter won't work for old versions either, from the docs: `In addition, apps that were created on older API versions but haven't been used won't be able to use older API versions`

Comment: that is indeed a case. It gave me some head scratching though.